# .NET Core Worker service not working on IIS

Tags: c#, .net-core, backgroundworker, iis-8, worker

I have developed one small worker application in .NET core and It is working locally but When I deployed on IIS It is not working I have already configured below setting on iis:
https://www.taithienbo.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-and-keep-it-running-on-iis/

Worker.cs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
        }
    }
```

Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Logger logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                }).
                UseNLog()
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
```

Comment: Share the code, the error, what you have tried so far.

Comment: What is not working? Do you get an error? What have you tried to solve/debug it?

Comment: Basically I have simply write the log after every 1 millisecond so When I published worker service application on IIS that time It is not start automatically. I have also check the permission of the user whether user has permission to write the file or not.

Comment: I am not facing any error because in local It is working.

Comment: Long running services are not designed for IIS. So, you should use a Windows service, a container, or Azure. You probably use IIS Express when claiming "in local It is working", but IIS Express is not IIS, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

I would like to inform you that the IIS is best suitable to host Web applications.

Hosting a Worker Service application on the IIS might not be the best choice and it may not work as you expected.

As suggested by Lex Li, you could host it in a Windows Service.

For more detailed information, you could refer to [Host ASP.NET Core in a Windows Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the worker process is not created until the web application that is hosted it is instantiated, this will need to be done by calling  an endpoint such as the 'Heatlhz' endpoint. At this point, the startup will create the service and the background service will begin to do it's work.

We have used this pattern to mostly good effect in order to host a background service in IIS, albeit one that had an iterative processing on records and could cope with being restarted via app pool recyles etc. The healtcheck endpoint is added to an automated system that will periodically call and this deals with restarting the background service if required.

I would agree with the comments of others that for certain scenarios, especially longer running processes, a windows service or a scheduled console application might be better suited.